# react render values from an array gives error

Tags: reactjs

I have react component like:

```
 class UserList extends Component {
      render() {
        const {users} = this.props
        users.forEach(function(user){
            console.log(user.name)
            if(user.photos){
                console.log(user.photos.data[0].source)
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{user.name}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
      }
    }

    export default UserList
```

But it is giving me error saying `should return valid react component but returned array or undefined`..

The return function should return the component right ?

What am I missing here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states you need to return a valid React element.

The fix is to return a DOM node from your `render`, a `div` for example.

```
class UserList extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}
```

Further more using `.forEach` will not return a valid React element to the div, use `.map` instead to produce an array that you render.

```
class UserList extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{ 
            this.props.users
                .filter(user => user.photos)
                .map((user) => {
                    return <li>{ user.name }</li>;
            }}
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `.filter` will take care of that.

Comment: If no photos I dont want to display the name.. also `photos` contains `images` like `photos[0] photos[1]` so how to display them with name ?

Comment: The `.filter` will take care of seeing if you have any photos and displaying images is done as normal `{ user.photos[0].propertyOfImageObject }`.

Comment: User which does not have `photos` is not displaying and giving error..  `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: User without photos should not be displayed as per your if statement in your question. The error you're getting is easily read up in the React Docs. I'm not going to write your app for you.

Comment: If user dont have photos it should not be displayed like I checked in javascript it only display if user have photos else not